# Updating class instance object variables in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I thought i had a pretty good grasp at Typescript, but i am kind of stumped on this issue.

After creating an instance of my class, i want to update the values of the instance.

To do that i am writing a class method that takes incoming data parameters and assigns them to the 'this' context of that class instance.

I am however not able to update the instance of the class as Typescript complains that my object key is `readonly`, which i don't really see.

**My Class**

```
export interface theInterface {
    x_value: number;
    y_value: number;
  };
  
  export class theClass implements theInterface {
    public x_value: number;
    public y_value: number;

    constructor(public data: theInterface) {
      Object.assign(this, data);
    }
  
   public setValues(incoming_data: theInterface) {
        this.data.x_value = incoming_data.x_value; 
        this.data.y_value = incoming_data.y_value;
        // SAME ERROR WHEN TRYING TO SET VALUES LIKE THIS
        this.x_value = incoming_data.x_value; 
        this.y_value = incoming_data.y_value;
    }
  }
```

// MEANWHILE. IN A DIFFERENT PART OF THE CODEBASE

```
  let thing = new theClass({
    x_value: 10,
    y_value: 20
  });

  thing.setValues({
    x_value: 22,
    y_value: 55
  });
```

Running the `setValues` class method returns the error:

`'Cannot assign to read only property 'x_value' of object '[object Object]''`

I am suspecting i am missing something obvious and trivial, as having to update object values on a instance of a class, should be a very common use case.

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using? Try changing the `Object.assign` method in the constructor to individually assigning the values i.e. `this.x_value = data.x_value;`

Comment: Here's a REPL shorturl.at/bjrHZ

Comment: The Typescript version is version 4.7.2

Comment: I have tried writing the above code in the Typescript playground here:
shorturl.at/fjmNW

It does however not fail, but inserts a data key intro into the class instance

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the exact same errors as you did, but instead got

```
test.ts:7:12 - error TS2564: Property 'x_value' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

7     public x_value: number;
             ~~~~~~~
test.ts:8:12 - error TS2564: Property 'y_value' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

8     public y_value: number;
             ~~~~~~~
```

I don't know what's going on in your constructor, but what you probably want to be doing is this:

```js
constructor(data: theInterface) {
  this.x_value = data.x_value;
  this.y_value = data.y_value;
}
```

With the full code below which works:

```js
export interface theInterface {
    x_value: number;
    y_value: number;
};

export class theClass implements theInterface {
    public x_value: number;
    public y_value: number;

    constructor(data: theInterface) {
        this.x_value = data.x_value;
        this.y_value = data.y_value;
    }

    public setValues(incoming_data: theInterface) {
        this.x_value = incoming_data.x_value;
        this.y_value = incoming_data.y_value;
    }
}

let thing = new theClass({
    x_value: 10,
    y_value: 20
});

thing.setValues({
    x_value: 22,
    y_value: 55
});

console.log(thing);  // theClass { x_value: 22, y_value: 55 }
```